# Android, AsyncTask, onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute not being called

Tags: android, android-asynctask

After `doInBackground` finishes what it does, `onPostExecute` not get called. and if I try to publish a progress, `onProgressUpdate` not get called too.

I recreated an asyncTask that does nothing in the background but logging a text and yet both methods not get called.

Here is my code

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Void> {

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Object... params) {
    Log.d("MyAsyncTask","doInBackground");
    publishProgress(1);
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    Log.d("MyAsyncTask","onPostExecute");
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    Log.d("MyAsyncTask","onProgressUpdate");
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}}
```

and here is how I call it

```
new MyAsyncTask().execute();
```

Comment: Maybe post your `AsyncTask` and how you call it, otherwise there can be no answer to this "question"

Comment: Are you relying on logs to know that the methods aren't being called or have you tried setting breakpoints?

Comment: Where are you executing "new MyAsyncTask().execute();"? Is it on the Main Thread? And you task above requires an Object like "new MyAsyncTask().execute(Object);".

Comment: @LarryMcKenzie yes, it's on the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using flurry jar in the project, and by removing it and re-adding it to the project, every thing worked fine... I don't know why but that's what solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Execute your task on main/UI thread:

```
new MyAsyncTask().execute("Test");
```

Asynctask:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.d("MyAsyncTask","MyAsyncTask Started");
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.d("MyAsyncTask",params[0] + " in background.");
        publishProgress(params[0]);
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        Log.d("MyAsyncTask","onProgressUpdate - " + values[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.d("MyAsyncTask","onPostExecute " + result);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I do. onPreExecute is called but onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute are not.

Answer (score 0):

if still relevant:
try 
`publishProgress(Integer.valueOf(1))`